# Java, Spring MVC , HibernateDAO Faactory

Tags: javascript, java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am working on this project where I have to get the user **selected package from the URL in the browser**and give discounts if they are eligible for a discount. So I wrote my validation by accessing the cookie, but those details are saved in the cookies, therefore if a user gets s**ubscribed to package A** and if a second user comes and **selects the package B** unfortunately, **he gets the price and details of package A** and the *validation is being done for the package A*. So ***is there any way to update the cookie every time as the page reloads***?
I have added a code snippet of the validation of the URL and the way of accessing the package details from DB!.

**Code Snippet**

```
 if (selectedPackage != null) {
            Map<String, MembershipPackage> membershipPackagesMap = this.masterDataManager.getMembershipPackages();
            MembershipPackage membershipPackage = membershipPackagesMap.get(selectedPackage);

            String selectedPKG = infoSelectedCountry;
            if(selectedPackage.equals("M_DSC_A")){
                membershipPackage.setPrice(membershipPackage.getDiscountPrice());
            }else{
                membershipPackage.setPrice(membershipPackage.getPrice());
            }
//Code Snippet for other users visting from other sites to buy packages
List<CountryDTO> sortedCountryList = this.masterDataManager.getSortedCountries(language);
        String selectedPackage;
        String leadSource = getLeadSourceFromCookie(request);
        if (CommonUtils.isNullOrEmptyString(infoSelectedPackage)) {
            selectedPackage = getSelectedPackageFromCookie(request);
            if (CommonUtils.isNullOrEmptyString(leadSource)) {
                leadSource = IPaymentConstants.LeadSource.B`enter code here`_SOURCE.getCode();
            }
        } else {
            selectedPackage = infoSelectedPackage.trim().substring(2);
            leadSource = infoSelectedPackage.trim().split("_")[0];

            if (!IPaymentConstants.LeadSource.X_INFO.getCode().equals(leadSource) && !IPaymentConstants.LeadSource.Y_SOURCE.getCode().equals(leadSource)) {
                return ViewNames.VIEW_NAME_404;
            }
```

Comment: You are trying to do validation based on cookie ? That seem's wrong to me. You should rather redesign your application than trying to resolve this problem. In addition your code will never work. You need to compare string using equals not "=="

Comment: I Thought if the user leaves at a point during any subscription process he/ she can continue their registrations form that point without starting from the beginning!